# registerForRemoteNotificationTypes causes app to exit immediately

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I'm seeing behaviour on my iPhone where debug builds immediately exit after a call to

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert];
```

The debugger reports it exited with the message

> Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination.

This behaviour doesn't happen on my ad hoc distribution builds. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Also weird: when I go to settings->notifications for my app, it says "off", and when I click on it, the page is blank - there are no switches to enable/disable badges, alerts, and sounds like there are for every other app.

Comment: Back again, dammit. Now it exits with:

Ignoring packet error, continuing...
gdb stack trace at 'putpkt: write failed':
0   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0018dc33 remote_backtrace_self + 54
1   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0019104b putpkt_binary + 401
2   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00191748 remote_macosx_get_all_image_infos_addr + 45
3   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00196345 remote_macosx_complete_create_or_attach + 146
4   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00196a0c 

Anyone have any clue? Deleting, rebooting and reinstalling doesn't work...